# Terraform: How to request AWS EC2 instances only in zones where the requested instance type is supported?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way to get the availability zones where an instance type (e.g. t3.medium) is available before requesting the instance? I'm trying to run the [following code](https://gist.github.com/vgiotsas/ce720f6744c5f25696078c143cc3ac79) and for certain regions it fails with the following error:

```
Error: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: Your requested instance type (t3.micro) is not supported in your requested Availability Zone (us-east-1e). Please retry your request by not specifying an Availability Zone or choosing us-east-1a, us-east-1b, us-east-1c, us-east-1d, us-east-1f.
```

Obviously I can manually specify the availability zone to one of the supported, but I want to minimize hardcoding availability zones.

Comment: Did you have chance to check the ec2_instance_type_offering resource? 
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_instance_type_offering

Comment: Thanks @DmitryKutetsky, that looks very promising! I'm trying it now

Comment: @DmitryKutetsky This data source basically only returns AWS names given a location, which is a bit the reverse of what I want.

Comment: probably, you need to check AWS API first to be sure that it CAN provide required method. After this, you can search for the related terraform resource (check the community providers as an option). Otherwise, terraform will not be able to do this since it works thorough AWS API, so if there is no method, terraform can't implement this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you're happy to spin up a different type of instance if the preferred type isn't available then you can use the [`aws_ec2_instance_type_offering` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_instance_type_offering) to instead fallback to the `t2` instance family in the affected availability zone.

The following Terraform code will output a map of availability zones to the instance type allowed, preferring `t3.micro` but falling back to `t2.micro`s where the `t3` family isn't available:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "all" {}

data "aws_ec2_instance_type_offering" "example" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)

  filter {
    name   = "instance-type"
    values = ["t2.micro", "t3.micro"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "location"
    values = [each.value]
  }

  location_type = "availability-zone"

  preferred_instance_types = ["t3.micro", "t2.micro"]
}

output "foo" {
  value = { for az, details in data.aws_ec2_instance_type_offering.example : az => details.instance_type }
}
```

This outputs:

```
foo = {
  "us-east-1a" = "t3.micro"
  "us-east-1b" = "t3.micro"
  "us-east-1c" = "t3.micro"
  "us-east-1d" = "t3.micro"
  "us-east-1e" = "t2.micro"
  "us-east-1f" = "t3.micro"
}
```

Instead of just outputting this you should be able to iterate over the availability zones to set the instance type for the `aws_instance` resource.

Alternatively you could filter the output to reduce it to just a list of the AZs that can offer the `t3` instance family by changing the output to the following:

```
output "foo" {
  value = keys({ for az, details in data.aws_ec2_instance_type_offering.example : az => details.instance_type if details.instance_type == "t3.micro" })
}
```

This outputs the following, skipping the availability zone that doesn't include the `t3` instance family:

```
foo = [
  "us-east-1a",
  "us-east-1b",
  "us-east-1c",
  "us-east-1d",
  "us-east-1f",
]
```

Comment: Thank you @ydaetskcoR! This is exactly what I was trying to do, I couldn't get the for loop right!