# Terraform: Handle error if no EC2 Instance Type offerings found in AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We are spinning up G4 instances in AWS through Terraform and often encounter issues where one or two of the AZs in the given Region don't support G4 Instance type.

As of now I have hardcoded our TF configuration as per below where I am creating a map of Region and AZs as "azs" variable. From this map I can spin up clusters in targeted AZs of the Region where we have G4 Instance support.

I am using aws command line mentioned in this [AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-type-not-supported-az-error/) to find which AZs are supported in a given Region and updating our "azs" variable as we expand to other Regions.

```
variable "azs" {
  default = {
    "us-west-2"      = "us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c"
    "us-east-1"      = "us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1e"
    "eu-west-1"      = "eu-west-1a,eu-west-1b,eu-west-1c"
    "eu-west-2"      = "eu-west-2a,eu-west-2b,eu-west-2c"
    "eu-west-3"      = "eu-west-3a,eu-west-3c"
 }
```

However the above approach required human intervention and updates frequently (If AWS adds support to non-supported AZs in a given region later on )

There is this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969173/terraform-how-to-request-aws-ec2-instances-only-in-zones-where-the-requested-in) where User is trying to do the same thing however he can use the fallback instance type lets say if any of the AZs are not supported for given instance type.

In my use-case , I can't use any other fall back instance type since our app-servers only runs on G4.

I have tried to use the workaround mentioned as an Answer in the above stack overflow question however its failing with the following error message.

> Error: no EC2 Instance Type Offerings found matching criteria; try
> different search
>
> on main.tf line 8, in data "aws_ec2_instance_type_offering"
> "example":    8: data "aws_ec2_instance_type_offering" "example" {

I am using the TF config as below where my `preferred_instance_types` is g4dn.xlarge.

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "2.70"
}
data "aws_availability_zones" "all" {
  state = "available"
}

data "aws_ec2_instance_type_offering" "example" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_availability_zones.all.names)
  filter {
    name   = "instance-type"
    values = ["g4dn.xlarge"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "location"
    values = [each.value]
  }
  location_type            = "availability-zone"
  preferred_instance_types = ["g4dn.xlarge"]
}

output "foo" {
  value = { for az, details in data.aws_ec2_instance_type_offering.example : az => details.instance_type }
}
```

I would like to know how to handle this failure as Terraform is not able to find the g4 instance type in one of the AZs of a given region and failing.

Is there any Terraform Error handling I can do to by pass this error for now and get the supported AZs as an Output ?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? If there are no `g4dn.xlarge` instances available, then do what?

Comment: If AZ doesn’t support g4dn.xlarge then skip it from the output rather than failing with Error.

Comment: Have you tried putting a dummy instance type (eg `t2.micro`) that you know exists in all the AZs and then using the filtering of AZs as described in that answer?

Comment: Yeah I have used dummy instance type or fall back in other words to not fail if `g4dn.xlarge` is not available in AZ. However those fall back instance types are also not available in some of the AZs too. The fall back instance types I have tried so far is `t2.micro` , `t2.nano` , `t3.micro` some C series as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had checked that other question you mentioned earlier, but i could never get the output correctly. Thanks to @ydaetskcoR for this response in that post - I could learn a bit and get my loop working.

Here is one way to accomplish what you are looking for... Let me know if it works for you.

Instead of "[aws_ec2_instance_type_offering](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_instance_type_offering)", use "[aws_ec2_instance_type_offerings](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_instance_type_offerings)"  ... (there is a 's' in the end. they are different Data Sources...

I will just paste the code here and assume you will be able to decode the logic. I am filtering for one specific instance type and if its not supported, instance_types will be black and i make a list of AZ thats does not do not have blank values.

```
variable "az" {
  default="us-east-1"
}

variable "my_inst" {
  default="g4dn.xlarge"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "example" {
  filter {
    name   = "opt-in-status"
    values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
  }
}

data "aws_ec2_instance_type_offerings" "example" {
for_each=toset(data.aws_availability_zones.example.names)

  filter {
    name   = "instance-type"
    values = [var.my_inst]
  }


  filter {
    name   = "location"
    values = ["${each.key}"]
  }

  location_type = "availability-zone"
}


output "az_where_inst_avail" {
  value = keys({ for az, details in data.aws_ec2_instance_type_offerings.example :
  az => details.instance_types if length(details.instance_types) != 0 })
}
```

The output will look like below.  us-east-1e does not have the instance type and its not there in the Output. Do test a few cases to see if it works everytime.

```
Outputs:

az_where_inst_avail = [
  "us-east-1a",
  "us-east-1b",
  "us-east-1c",
  "us-east-1d",
  "us-east-1f",
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a cleaner way. The data source already filters for the availability zone based off of the given filter. There is an attribute -> **locations** that will produce a list of the desired **location_type**.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

data "aws_ec2_instance_type_offerings" "available" {
  filter {
    name = "instance-type"
    values = [var.instance_type]
  }

  location_type = "availability-zone"
}

output "azs" {
  value = data.aws_ec2_instance_type_offerings.available.locations
}
```

Where the **instance_type** is t3.micro and **region** is us-east-1, this accurately produces:

```
azs = tolist([
  "us-east-1d",
  "us-east-1a",
  "us-east-1c",
  "us-east-1f",
  "us-east-1b",
])
```

You don't need to feed it a list of availability zones because it already gets those from the supplied region.